# Can the tags [whisky] and [whiskey] be merged?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

Both tags [whisky](https://alcohol.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/whisky) and [whiskey](https://alcohol.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/whiskey) refer to the same thing; they're just different spellings. Can these two tags be merged?

Comment: Thus should be easily done by moderators. In principle I agree with you.

Comment: @Ken who are the mods on this site, I've noticed a lot of un-closed questions and am a little concerned there are non

Comment: Look here for our [moderators](https://alcohol.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators).

Answer (score 5):

Note that the current descriptions aren't symmetrical:

> #### Whiskey:
>
> a type of distilled alcoholic beverage made from fermented grain mash. Various grains (which may be malted) are used for different varieties,

> #### Whisky:
>
> For questions relating to the subject of whisky. (Primarily Scotch, Canadian, and Japanese whisky.)

The second correctly notes that the "…ky" spelling is used for Scotch, Canadian, and Japanese whiskies.
This is not at all like the situation of "color" versus "colour" spellings; the spelling must match the origin of the drink, and is not simply an author's preferred spelling.

The first is a generic description, not saying that the "..key" spelling is used for Bourbon and Irish whiskeys.

Both are good ideas (so many other tags don't have any descriptions at all), but as they stand they don't complement each other.

But I think it unlikely that anyone would have a question about Canadian and Scotch while excluding Bourbon.
So while the "whisky" definition is good, I'd say there is really no need for such a specific tag.

The only question is which one to use as the real name and which as the alias?

Comment: [This section from the Wikipedia article on "whisky"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whisky#Names_and_spellings) may be of help: "The spelling *whiskey* is common in Ireland and the United States, while *whisky* is used in all other whisky-producing countries. In the US, the usage has not always been consistent. From the late eighteenth century to the mid twentieth century, American writers used both spellings interchangeably until the introduction of newspaper style guides. [...]"

Comment: "[...] Since the 1960s, American writers have increasingly used *whiskey* as the accepted spelling for aged grain spirits made in the US and *whisky* for aged grain spirits made outside the US. However, some prominent American brands, such as George Dickel, Maker's Mark, and Old Forester (all made by different companies), use the *whisky* spelling on their labels, and the Standards of Identity for Distilled Spirits, the legal regulations for spirit in the US, also use the *whisky* spelling throughout."

Comment: That said, judging solely from which tag is getting used more, it seems like [whiskey] is the more commonly used tag, so it might make sense to synonymize [whisky] to [whiskey], leaving the latter as the primary tag. (It's very easy for site mods to swap the order of the synonymization later if desired.)